# tryhandlebarsjs Register Helper functions

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am playing around with [tryhandlebarsjs.com](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/)

I have following function:

```
export const cellHelper = {
    name: "cell",
    handler: (context) => {
        //...
        return template
    }
}
```

If I pass it as is I get `Error(s): SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`. What is the correct syntax to pass it into [tryhandlebarsjs.com](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('cell', function(context) {
   //...
   return template
});
```